# Does SQLAlchemy support embedded class mapping?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Many Java ORMs support embedded class mappings, i.e. a relationship to a SCO which does not have a life of its own and is embedded in the table of the parent class, but I cannot find how to do this with SQLAlchemy.

E.g. Human has a Head and the Head attributes get mapped inline in the Human table.

Is this possible with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Perhaps [composites](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/composites.html) are what you're looking for?

Comment: It seems ugly to have to map the columns as attributes in addition to the composite attribute, but it seems to do the job. thanks!